# Do ajax-query for count clicks on link

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, post

I must count clicks on link and pass result to php-file.I think that it do by dint of ajax-query.

```
<a class='link' href='www.site.com'>Open</a>

<script>
var count=0;
$('.link').on('click',function(){
count+=1;
});
</script>
```

What must I do next? How can I pass count to array POST or Get?

Comment: What is the purpose of count in php file?

Comment: you need add onclick function to a link and add it in script tag

Comment: If you want to send to PHP, use ajax but remember that PHP doesn't save the state, once it executes the script then it done. You need a method to save the value (save to text, database, session, etc)

Comment: @RahulRaut php-file for a treatment of results

Comment: @ShireeshaParampalli, how mist I do it?

Comment: @catcon, yes, I want do ajax-query to php-file and save result to database. But I don't know do for this.
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'test.php',
    data: {count:count},
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
    }
});

On php-file:
print_r($_POST['count'];

But I have error - undefined index 'count' in test.php

Comment: @Alexey_Danilov Are you saving count in database or just using it in php file?

Comment: @Alexey_Danilov You don't need to send count. You just need to send something that will trigger your PHP script. Then simply get the current count value and increase it.

Comment: Is the error come from ajax or you access the test.php from the browser and it throws that error?

Comment: @RahulRaut js->php-file($count=$_POST['count'])->db

Comment: @PHPnoob how can I do it?

Comment: @catcon error is in test.php

Comment: Like I said, PHP doesn't hold the value when you send the ajax and then wait for you to view it if you don't use the method I mention above. I think you need to stop trying to code, just get the basic straight then you can countinue, otherwise you're gonna have hard times understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to count clicks on some link, then you have to use file or database to save the value, because PHP does not save the state.

Here I am giving an example of using a database for this:

> The Ajax

```
$('.link').on('click',function(){
  $.ajax({
      url:"<?php echo 'Your url to incrementCount() method';?>",
      method:"POST",
      data:{},
      success:function(response){
          // on success do something
      }                    
  });
});
```

> The PHP method

```
public function incrementCount(){
  $UpdateQuery = "UPDATE link_counts SET link_count=link_count + 1 WHERE id=1";
  // here 'link_counts' is table name and 'link_count' is the column name to update
  $result = mysql_query($UpdateQuery );
}
```

> The 'link_counts' table

```
-------+------------+
|  id  | link_count |
-------+------------+
```

Here `link_count` column value is 0 by default. By this, you can update the field on the occurrence of click event of `.link` class.

Alternatively, you can use `user_id` to count which user clicked the `.link` class. To achieve this you need to add some `where` condition to the update query.

If you want to do this with a file, then change the PHP method by below code-

> PHP Method for file handling

```
$file = 'link_counter.txt';

// default the counter value to 1
$counter = 1;

// add the previous counter value if the file exists    
if (file_exists($file)) {
    $counter += file_get_contents($file);
}

// write the new counter value to the file
file_put_contents($file, $counter);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

To count the clicks on a link you should pass something like the ID of the link ( from db ) or another identifier which you can use to increment the count on the server - if you were to try to send the updated count from the client it would be vulnerable to abuse ~ it would be very easy to modify the count if desired.

You could use ajax as in the following, untested, example - it might give you the idea of how to proceed.

```
<?php

    /* test.php */

    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && !empty( $_POST['id'] ) && !empty( $_POST['url'] ) ){
        $id=$_POST['id'];
        $url=$_POST['url'];

        $sql='update `links` set `count`=`count`+1 where `id`=? and `url`=?';
        $stmt=$db->prepare($sql);

        if( $stmt ){
            $stmt->bind_param('is', $id, $url );
            $res=$stmt->execute();

            exit( $url );
        }
        exit( false );
    }


?>
```

And the html & javascript snippets

```
<a id=1 href='www.site.com' class='link'>Open Site</a>
<a id=2 href='www.example.com' class='link'>Open Example</a>
<a id=3 href='www.banana.com' class='link'>Open Banana</a>
<a id=4 href='www.spitfire.com' class='link'>Open Spitfire</a>
<a id=5 href='www.hellcat.com' class='link'>Open Hellcat</a>


<script>
    const ajax=function( url, params, callback ){
        with( new XMLHttpRequest() ){
            onreadystatechange=function(e){
                if( this.status==200 && this.readyState==4 )callback.call( this, this.response )
            }
            open( 'POST', url, true );
            setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
            send( params );
        }
    };

    const clickcallback=function(r){
        if( r )window.open( r )
    };

    const clickhandler=function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        let url='test.php';
        let params='id='+e.target.id+'&url='+encodeURI( e.target.href );
        ajax.call( this, url, params, clickcallback  )
    };


    Array.prototype.slice.call( document.querySelectorAll('a.link') ).forEach( a=>{
        a.addEventListener('click', clickhandler );
    })
</script>
```